# Use the formal definition of the derivative to find the derivative of $f(x) = \frac1x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Working through some exercises which I have been set in a Stats module.

I'm stuck on this problem. I can get to
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac1{x+h}-\frac1x}h.$$

Then I'm unsure as to where to go from there in order to get $-\frac1{x^2}.$

Thanks

Comment: I seeyou're a new user. Please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by doing some algebra:

$$ f(x+h) - f(x) = \frac{ 1}{x+h} - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{x - x - h}{x(x+h)} = \frac{-h}{x(x+h)}$$

Hence,

$$ \phi(h) =  \frac{ f(x+h)-f(x) }{h} = \frac{ \frac{-h}{x(x+h)}}{h}= \frac{-1}{x(x+h)}$$

Now, what happens

$$ \lim_{h \to 0 } \phi(h) $$

???

Arithmetic Fact:

$$ \frac{ \frac{a}{b} }{ \frac{c}{d} } = \frac{ad}{bc}$$

Comment: Sorry, I dont mean to be a pain. How did you get from

$$\frac{ \frac{-h}{x(x+h)}}{h} to \frac{-1}{x(x+h)}$$

That's where I'm going wrong

Comment: @Samuel $\dfrac {\frac a b}c=\dfrac a{bc}$, a bit more generally and useful to know is $\dfrac {\frac a b}{\frac cd}=\dfrac {ad}{bc}$.

Answer (score 1):

Simply compute

$$\frac{\frac1{x+h}-\frac1x}h=\frac{-h}{h(x+h)x}$$

and cancel the factor $h$. Then, the limit is trivial (no indeterminations or other difficulties).