# What is the first derivative of $1\over x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to find out the first derivative of $1\over x$ but I'm not sure how.
Can someone provide detailed explanation? Thank you.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Do you know the quotient rule?

Comment: Using the power rule, 
$\big(\dfrac{1}{x}\big)' = (x^{-1})' = -(x^{-2}) = -\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}
$. What part don't you understand?

Comment: Why all the downvotes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use the formal definition of the derivative to find the derivative of $f(x) = \frac1x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967734/use-the-formal-definition-of-the-derivative-to-find-the-derivative-of-fx-f)

Comment: basic calculus, read the lecture

Answer (score 6):

Using the definition $\frac{d}{dx}(x^a)=ax^{a-1},~a\in\mathbb{R}$, we can write $$(\frac{1}{x})'=(x^{-1})'=-x^{-2}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$ where $'$ denotes the first derivative.
Alternatively, you can use differentiation by first principles via the formula
$$
\frac{df}{dx}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$$
for $f(x)=x^a.$

Answer (score 2):

The "power rule" states that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}x^{\alpha} = \alpha x^{\alpha-1}.$$  Now, since we can write $$\frac{1}{x}  = x^{-1}$$ and apply the power law with $\alpha = -1$ we get $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{1}{x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} x^{-1} = (-1)x^{-1-1} = - \frac{1}{x^2}$$ since we can write $x^{-1-1} = x^{-2}$ as $\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

From the definition of the derivative:

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\frac{1}{x+h}-\frac{1}{x}}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-h}{hx(x+h)}=
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-1}{x(x+h)}= -\frac{1}{x^2}$$